# Changing MySQL connections based on state

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How would one check for first available MySQL database connection and use it?

What I managed so far:

I have a xml file in which i store my MySQL connection strings (i know it's not safest way but i'm not concerned about security as all mysql users will have only select rights enabled). My function in which i get strings is:

```
Public Function getDbInfo()
    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
    xmlDoc.Load(Globals.rootPath & "settings.xml")
    Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Database")
    Dim pID As String = "", pName As String = "", pString As String = ""
    For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
        pID = node.SelectSingleNode("database_id").InnerText
        pName = node.SelectSingleNode("database_name").InnerText
        pString = node.SelectSingleNode("database_string").InnerText

    Next
    Return pString
End Function
```

In my 'Gobals.vb' which is Public Class I have:

```
Public Shared databaseInfo = ""
```

databaseInfo should hold first available MySQL connection string, pID in a public function above is an AutoIncrement int(11).

What is the best aproach to implement function which will check mysql connection strings and set databaseInfo on first available/possible to connect connection string so i can use that database in my MySQL class.

This is my function for connecting/disconnecting from database:

```
  Dim konekcija As String = Globals.databaseInfo

Public Function ManageConnection(ByVal CloseConnection As Boolean, ByVal konekcija As String)
    Try

        dbCon = New MySqlConnection(konekcija)
        If CloseConnection = False Then
            If dbCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then _
                    dbCon.Open()
            Console.WriteLine(konekcija)
        Else
            dbCon.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception


    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: What do you mean by _first available MySQL connection string_?

Comment: First connection that does not throw exception. I have updated my quesiton with my manageConnection function @David

Comment: But what I meant is, how does is know which is the first, or which one to try and open first?

Comment: As i wrote above, xml file holds 4 database strings and database_id is auto increment int(11), for each loop already shows all the data. @David

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're asking in that case... If you're looping over each connection, trying to open it then wanting to use the first one that opens, what is wrong with what you have? Just try opening the connection, if it works, use a global variable (MySQL Connection variable) and assign the connection to be the one you tested.

Comment: @David How would i stop a for each loop if function return True. ie, if i check for bool inside getDbInfo function, specificaly inside for each loop.
I want to edit for each loop to stop looping if smth = true

Comment: Use an `If` statement. `If x = True Then` followed by `Exit For`, then `End If`

Comment: Has this solved your issue?